# Looking for Outlook Office Web Appointment OOTB "Delete" button event handler

Tags: office-addins, outlook-web-addins

As we are able to track **OnSend** event on **send button**. Is it possible to track **delete event** on **delete button** while deleting the event? Please see the below screenshot for the same.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPJkI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Currently delete event is not a part of the product.

We track Outlook add-in feature requests on [our user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.